# sum of records on each page separately and total sum of all pages in rdlc report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I have a report built with RDLC (Microsoft Report).

I have so many records in so many pages that I want show the sum of a column for each page separately and sum of records that come from previous pages.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You're not providing quite enough details, most notably [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far to solve this (and why it didn't work). Note that you can edit your question to add more details at any time, and -if substantial- this will bump your question for renewed attention as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see is to group your results by a set number of rows by a formula in your query, then force a page break on this group.

Add this field to your SQL: `CEIL(rownum/25) as page_group`

Then in you query you will need to sum for the rows in each group and sum for all the preceeding rows.

`=SUM(column1)` will will be your standard sum function but try `=SUM(IIf(page_group<=page_group, column1, 0), my_dataset)` for all preceeding groups.

Good luck.

Comment: i want sum of records for each page seperately in rdlc. ok?

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. could you please help me how to group my result?